# Proper way of using ViewModel and LiveData

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-livedata

I'm confused a little bit about ViewModel and LiveData.
I plan to refactor my app to use these components, but I'm not sure are they good for me.

I develop a newsreader app.
Now I have two activities:
Activity A for covers (in my case, 5 fragments in a ViewPager with list of the articles)
and Activity B that also contains a ViewPager with Fragments, and the fragments displays the details of the articles.

I plan to migrate Activity A and B to fragments and use a single activity with ViewModel and LiveData.

Would it be a good solution to instantiate a ViewModel that contains the list of the articles wrapped in LiveData for each Fragment?
I mean in my case in the Activity there would be five instances of ViewModel that hold a list of the articles.
Is this the proper way in my case?

Answer (score 0):

You should consult Google's official documentation on Android JetPack to learn how to use ViewModel and LiveData properly in your app: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide